# call tracker-search from php

Tags: php, tracker

I try to run gnome tracker-search from php. For example like this:

```
<?php
   $result = shell_exec("/usr/bin/tracker-search -l 5 --disable-snippets --disable-color test");
   echo "<pre>$result</pre>";
?>
```

But the output is empty. When I run `/usr/bin/tracker-search --help` in php, I get the help output. I also try to put tracker-search in the visudo file, but it have also no effect.

Have anybody an Idea what's happen here?

Comment: `print_r($result)`  or `var_dump($result);` should help you out. don't use echo , you might be having a array in return.

Comment: Thank you! But sadly this is not enough. with ```var_dump($result);```I get ```NULL```.

Comment: then the response is nul

Comment: as per the [docs](http://php.net/shell_exec): `... or NULL if an error occurred or the command produces no output. `

Comment: Yes this I understand, but I don't understand why tracker-search gives no output. When it gets called it always give something back, also when the search result is empty.

Comment: Ok I have it now... I need to import the tracker environment variables again.
http://netatalk.sourceforge.net/3.1/htmldocs/configuration.html
Under "Using Tracker commandline tools on the server".